# Access Conditional Formatting

Tags: ms-access

I have table with name Festivals and inside the table there are fields for duration of festivals. The name of one field is **StartOfFestival** which is when festival starts and other field is **EndOfFestival** which is when it ends.

I made a query. Inside this query, I made expression to join this fields together. 
For example if festival starts *`07/07/2018`* and ends *`09/07/2018`* it will display as `07/07/2018-09/07/2018`. 
Then I made report based on this query. Report name is `Festivals`. If the festival is over I want to paint it red in report if not then green.
 I tried conditional formatting but it doesn't work right. I think that expression which I made in query is messing this up. But I don't want to delete it. So how can I put expression in conditional formatting?
Thanks for help guys.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another calculated field to your query that will return True/False (-1/0) if the date is later than todays date.  Something like `[MyDate]<Date() AS IsFinished`.

On your report add a textbox to fill the *Detail* section of the report and set its control source to the new field.  Send the text box to the back so it sits behind all other controls.

Now give the textbox conditional formatting of *Field Value Is True* and format the textbox to red background with red text.

Or, if you just want the text colour red you can do without the "background" textbox and conditionally format each textbox with something like `Expression Is [IsFinished]=True`.